# How to do an Include on two navigation properties, where both might get the same reference?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

Given these example models:

```
public class Equipment : DataModelBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Equipment ID")]
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value, () => ID);
    }

    //lots of other properties...

    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    [Display(Name = "Vendor ID")]
    public Int32? VendorID
    {
        get => _vendorID;
        set => SetProperty(ref _vendorID, value, () => VendorID);
    }

    [Display(Name = "Vendor")]
    public Supplier Vendor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Manufacturer")]
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer ID")]
    public Int32? ManufacturerID
    {
        get => _manufacturerID;
        set => SetProperty(ref _manufacturerID, value, () => ManufacturerID);
    }

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public Supplier Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier : DataModelBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Supplier ID")]
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value, () => ID); }
    }
}
```

It is expected that the `Vendor` and `Manufacturer` properties on the `Equipment` model could reference the same `Supplier`.  The problem is that when the `Equipment` entity is used in a view, the bindings point to the exact same entity, meaning that when my UI selects a value for one, the other property changes as well because the binding is to the same object in memory.

They are loaded into a view model using a query such as this:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var eqList = context.Equipment
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(eq => eq.Vendor)
                        .Include(eq => eq.Manufacturer)
                        .ToList();
}
```

To me, it seems like **EF Core** is realizing that the two `Supplier` references are the same and then only creating one instance and applying it to both properties.

So my question is, is it possible to rewrite this query in such a way as to force **EF Core** to pull two unique instances of the `Supplier` reference (one for each navigation property) for the `Equipment` entity, instead of it pulling the same one for both?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want the same value to be different in two places. In general it's not a good idea to directly bind your model to the view.

Comment: @AirLancer First of all it's not.  These things exist in a view model, where properties expose the selected entities.  That seems beside the point, however.  It's not the same value.  From the perspective of the `Equipment` entity, it's two values that happen to be the same.  `Supplier` is a common list in the database, shared entries.  `Equipment` provides two places to store selections from that list.

Comment: This appears to be an XY problem, caused by missing information, namely the way you bind your viewmodel and its updates. You can't let EF create an instance per entity, because the change tracker doesn't support that. So, create a [mcve] including your MVC/controller code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Perhaps.  Or I'm just approaching it the wrong way.  In either case, feel free to suggest something.  An example isn't going to help you to understand this scenario any better.  It's either possible to keep two properties with the same entity, or it isn't.

Comment: It is. If it isn't in your scenario, you must explain your scenario better.